# The convergence or divergence of the $\int_{1}^{\infty}\ln (\cos\frac{1}{x}+\sin\frac{1}{x}) \Bbb{d}x$

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

The problem is:

> Judge whether or not the $\int_{1}^{\infty}\ln (\cos\frac{1}{x}+\sin\frac{1}{x}) \Bbb{d}x$ convergent.

I substitute the $\frac{1}{x}$ with $t$ and get $$-\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln (\cos \frac{1}{t}+\sin \frac{1}{t})}{t^2}\Bbb{d}t,$$ but I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

The substitution is used to make the integral simpler, but yours make it more difficult. Consider the integral by part,
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}\ln \left(\cos\frac{1}{x}+\sin\frac{1}{x}\right) \ dx = x\ln \left(\cos\frac{1}{x}+\sin\frac{1}{x}\right)\Bigg|_1^\infty-\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin\frac{1}{x}-\cos\frac{1}{x}}{x^2\left(\sin\frac{1}{x}+\cos\frac{1}{x}\right)} \ dx
$$
and see what you can conclude from this.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I integral by part and get the following: $\int_{1}^{\infty}\ln \left(\cos\frac{1}{x}+\sin\frac{1}{x}\right) \ dx = x\ln \left(\cos\frac{1}{x}+\sin\frac{1}{x}\right)\Bigg|_1^\infty-\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin\frac{1}{x}-\cos\frac{1}{x}}{x\left(\sin\frac{1}{x}+\cos\frac{1}{x}\right)} \ dx$

Comment: Sorry, the first term was a typo. Check [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln%28cos%281%2Fx%29%2Bsin%281%2Fx%29%29derivative) for the integral part.